# How to check signal is available or not in android 2.2

Tags: android

I am creating an android app & in that I need to call an emergency number if the network or signal is not available.How can I do that.Please provide the code.Please reply at the earliest.Thank You!

Comment: does this have anything to do with programming? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method:

```
public Boolean isNetAvailable(Context context)  {      
        try{
           ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)                                                                               context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);             
          NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                if (mobileInfo.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception Connectivity", e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()){
        //Signal is available
    }
```

Hope it helps ;)